# Socket.Connect to SMTP to verify email always returns with smtp connection timeout

Tags: asp.net, sockets, email, smtp, timeout

I've written a tool that validates emails, mostly copied from various examples on the subject around on the internet (user [Don Worthley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37225/don-worthley) compiled a decent collection of code samples here https://delicious.com/dworthley/email.validation).  Unfortunately after creating the socket and the IPEndPoint from the email to verify's hostname IP and port, my code always fails to connect to the socket due to timeout.

Here is the pertinent code (fails at s.Connect(endPt) due to timeout):

```
private bool smtpCheckEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
        string[] host = (email.Split('@'));
        string hostname = host[1];
        IPHostEntry IPhst = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
        IPEndPoint endPt = new IPEndPoint(IPhst.AddressList[0], 25);

        using (Socket s = new Socket(endPt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            try
            {
                s.Connect(endPt);
            }
            catch
            {
                s.Close();
                return false;
            }
```

From my research others have reported success with similar code so it might be an issue with my server host.  The MVC project is on a GoDaddy VPS with Windows 7 and standard firewall/MSSE as protection (I've tested with both disabled with same timeout result).

I've verified I can telnet to my own host and run through the various HELO, Mail from etc commands but it also times out if I try to connect to smtp for other hosts.

Maybe it's an ISP issue?

I've also tried installing [EmailVerify for .NET](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/validate-address) trial but run into the same problem where any validation at or above SMTP check times out.

Would be great to get some suggestions of what might be the problem and how to troubleshoot it.

Edit: After doing some comparison testing with one of my Azure VPS it looks like it is likely to be server related, "telnet 74.125.206.108 smtp" (gmail's smtp host IP) through command line connects on the Azure box but not on the GoDaddy one my project is on.

I also notice that when my code pulls the IP from the host name (Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)), in this gmail example it returns 216.58.216.37 which matches what I get if a run nslookup in cmd for gmail.com, however the IP for smtp that I can telnet to is for gmail is 74.125.206.108 which matches the nslookup record for smtp.gmail.com.  Could my code be grabbing the wrong IP addresses in many cases here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a limitation of GoDaddy VPS.  Transferred code to an Azure hosted project and it worked great.